# ISSUE to autoplay youtube videos on my ionic application

Tags: javascript, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 for my application, I have ion-slides of videos which it'd be good to autoplay the videos while sliding.

There's an `<iframe>` inside the slide that autoplays vimeo or youtube videos. The vimeo videos already work with this solution, but youtube videos are not working.

```
<iframe allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/311263132?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;background=1&amp;silenciado=1"></iframe>

<iframe allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CjxugyZCfuw?autoplay=1&amp;version=3&amp;loop=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;mute=1&amp;playlist=CjxugyZCfuw"></iframe>
```

Those two codes autoplay on codepen, but when I put them in my project, stop working.

Part of the code looks like that:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let c of contents; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="c.url | videoPlay as video">
      <iframe [src]="video.url" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
    </div>
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

The videoPlay only identify if it's vimeo or youtube and add the parameters according to it

Comment: youtube videos need autoplay=1 flag in the videourl and also it should be embed url